# May one eat cheese that is wormy?

Tags: halacha, food, dairy, bugs, non-kosher-species

[Nitei Gavriel Shavuos 29:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46443&st=&pgnum=178&hilite=) says that one may eat cheese that has worms in it, and there is no prohibition of Sheretz on it. Is this accurate? Does everyone agree with this?

Comment: Scientists don't :)

Comment: @DoubleAA: neither would I.

Comment: Ewww.... [15 char]

Comment: Why does this question sound familiar?

Comment: @SethJ: I also thought we'd previously discussed spontaneous generation of worms in halacha before, but couldn't find it. (I seem to remember a question about the fish controversy).

Comment: See [this article](http://torahmusings.com/2013/01/kosher-worms-insects/), especially the fourth paragraph: "Similarly, one will often find worms in cheeses that are hard, aged, or otherwise prepared in a way that gives the cheese a very sharp taste. These worms are kosher and are permitted to be eaten as long as they remain embedded within the cheese...."

Comment: I believe it is the Taz who mentions casu marzu specifically.  In Sardinia, apparently people eat such things.